# How am I able to use the command "sha256sum x.img" "without" a network connection, and get a hash-response?

Tags: hashsum

I am under the impression that sha256sum pings the distro side of things and reads "THEIR" hash file for my .img and gives me that info in a hash-printout in my term.

If so, how I am able to get that info without being connected to the network?

I tried it a few times without the network connected, neither wifi or ethernet. Both times, with different images in different term's, I got a response. It makes me think the command is just reading MY "sha256sum.sha file that downloaded with the image. Maybe it is, either way, seems strange.

Debian 10 buster; 32-bit

Thanks.

Comment: What gave you that impression?

Comment: @muru I was given the wrong information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sha256sum x.img` calculates the SHA-256 checksum of `x.img`, locally. `sha256sum` can also verify checksums with the `-c` option, again locally. There’s no remote connectivity involved.

It’s up to you to either manually compare the output of `sha256sum x.img` with a published checksum, or download a checksum file and verify that. `sha256sum` doesn’t know about “official” checksums for anything.

Comment: Stephen, thanks.